# Shared preferences is working fine in debug mode of flutter web but after deploy it does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, web, sharedpreferences

this is the code for login button. when login button is pressed nothing happens.

login()async{
SharedPreferences prefs = await                   SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", true);
navigateToDashboard();
}

I want to save this value on login. afterwards i want to use this to check if user is logged in or not. if login true then navigate to dashboard otherwise navigate to login page.